# Can no longer use screenOrientation portrait after Android Studio upgrade

Tags: android

I have just upgraded Android Studio and am now getting an error on  android:screenOrientation="portrait". It says it is expecting "unspecified" or "fullSensor" to provide Chrome OS devices with a great experience. Is there some way around this? I have tried putting
  
in the manifest but that doesn't work. What am I missing, portrait still appears to be an option in the documentation?

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Actually that is not the error. Warning message you can ignore it that's no issues.

Comment: It is coming up red, warnings are yellow unless they have changed that as well.

Comment: It looks as though I can do this: tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can request orientation to onCreate method with this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);